# How do I disable execution_duration_monitoring?

Tags: moveit, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the [fanuc](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc) package for ROS-Industrial and when launching the [moveit_planning_execution.launch](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/blob/indigo-devel/fanuc_m10ia_moveit_config/launch/moveit_planning_execution.launch) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1415027195.809289492]: Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory (the expected upper bound for the trajectory execution was 4.992567 seconds). Stopping trajectory.
```

The error is explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Troubleshooting/MoveIt%20Trajectory%20Execution%20Manager). What I understand is that I have to add a line in one of the launch file, something like:

```
<param name="execution_duration_monitoring" value="false"/>
```

I tried 2 things without success:

[trajectory_execution.launch.xml](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/blob/indigo-devel/fanuc_m10ia_moveit_config/launch/trajectory_execution.launch.xml)

```
  <!-- When determining the expected duration of a trajectory, this multiplicative factor is applied to get the allowed duration of execution -->
  <param name="allowed_execution_duration_scaling" value="1.2"/> <!-- default 1.2 -->
  <!-- Allow more than the expected execution time before triggering a trajectory cancel (applied after scaling) -->
  <param name="allowed_goal_duration_margin" value="0.5"/> <!-- default 0.5 -->
  <param name="execution_duration_monitoring" value="false"/>
```

And [move_group.launch](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/blob/indigo-devel/fanuc_m10ia_moveit_config/launch/move_group.launch)

```
<!-- Start the actual move_group node/action server -->
<node name="move_group" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" pkg="moveit_ros_move_group" type="move_group" respawn="false" output="screen" args="$(arg command_args)">
<!-- Set the display variable, in case OpenGL code is used internally -->
<env name="DISPLAY" value="$(optenv DISPLAY :0)" />
<param name="allow_trajectory_execution" value="$(arg allow_trajectory_execution)"/>
<param name="max_safe_path_cost" value="$(arg max_safe_path_cost)"/>
<param name="jiggle_fraction" value="$(arg jiggle_fraction)" />
<param name="execution_duration_monitoring" value="false" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196586/how-do-i-disable-execution_duration_monitoring-?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From looking at the code, i think the parameter is in a sub namespace "trajectory_execution/".
(Found in [trajectory_execution_manager.cpp](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/indigo-devel/planning/trajectory_execution_manager/src/trajectory_execution_manager.cpp) line 57)

The following should work in trajectory_execution.launch.xml

```
<param name="trajectory_execution/execution_duration_monitoring" value="false" />
```

Instead of disabling execution duration monitoring you can increase the time for your manipulator.

```
<param name="allowed_execution_duration_scaling" value="3.0"/>
```

Though, this param seems to exist in both namespaces?!

---

Originally posted by [jowave](https://answers.ros.org/users/20715/jowave/) with karma: 66 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2014-11-12**:
How did you find that the parameter is in a sub namespace?

**Comment by [jowave](https://answers.ros.org/users/20715/jowave/) on 2014-11-12**:
the dynamic_reconfigure member is created with ros::NodeHandle("~/trajectory_execution")

**Comment by [Danielwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/70765/danielwang/) on 2022-05-07**:
I added it in execution.launch but the program is stuck without any error．　Added it in trajectory_execution.launch.xml it doesn't work for me

here is the detailes:
INFO] [1651917001.823645112]: RRTConnect: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1651917001.834686270]: RRTConnect: Created 4 states (2 start + 2 goal)
[ INFO] [1651917001.834708564]: Solution found in 0.011150 seconds
[ INFO] [1651917001.838256444]: SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.003467 seconds and changed from 3 to 2 states
[ INFO] [1651917001.846145073]: Received new goal
[ INFO] [1651917001.846224835]: Trajectory received and accepted
[ INFO] [1651917001.846269192]: Translating trajectory
[ INFO] [1651917001.846292990]: Executing trajectory with 18 points and duration of 7.252s
[ INFO] [1651917001.846306611]: Attempting to start follower 0x21cf8e0
[ INFO] [1651917001.846315499]: Uploading trajectory program to robot

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had the same issue with controlling a Kinova MICO arm using MoveIt!. Placing the following lines in our launch file seems to have fixed all issues related to controller time-out as well as goal tolerances.

```
<param name="move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_execution_duration_scaling" value="4.0" />
<param name="move_group/trajectory_execution/execution_duration_monitoring" value="false" />
```

We found this by looking at the namespaces in rqt_reconfigure for move_group -> trajectory_execution.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [MahdiehNejati](https://answers.ros.org/users/24953/mahdiehnejati/) with karma: 86 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nofear123](https://answers.ros.org/users/39555/nofear123/) on 2019-12-06**:
Yes, it helped. Thank you .

**Comment by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on 2020-12-13**:
Wow, I can't believe I just ran into this post and still found it useful! Thanks, Rico

**Comment by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on 2021-03-10**:
This helped me too! I only scaled up the allowed_execution_duration_scaling parameter to 4. I left the 'execution_duration_monitoring' param at its default value. I ran into another issue though where I was seeing a GOAL_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED error. However, increasing the goal_time parameter to '1' in my controllers.yaml file solved that issue. Note that this wasn't with a fanuc robot but with a custom arm I'm developing on.